# Make new array from existing array with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have arr in jquery that looks like this

```
var occupy = [{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 1},{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 2},...]
```

And I need to extract all id's who have same apx.

Comment: Do you mean where 2 or more items are having the same apx?

Comment: Can you please post what you tried?

Comment: I have a function whit argument apx and that function need to look in array and return array of id's who have same apx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pure javascript to do that, something like this :

```
var occupy = [{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 1},{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 2}];

var result = [];

for (var idx = 0; idx < occupy.length; idx++){
    var key = occupy[idx].apx;
    if (!result[key]){
        result[key] = [];
    }

    result[key].push(occupy[idx].id);
}

console.log(result);
```

the `result` object will contain arrays of `id` grouped by their `apx`.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/C7szw/ (you'll need to look at the console window to see the `result`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 <script>
       var occupy = [{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 1},{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 2}];
       var apx =[]
       $.each(occupy, function (index, item) {
           if(apx.indexOf(item["apx"])==-1)
              apx.push(item["apx"]);
       });
       var ids =[];
       var temp;
       $.each(occupy, function (i, item) {
           var it = item;
           $.each(apx,function(j,a){
               if(a===item["apx"])
                   return ids.push(occupy[i]["id"]);
           });
       });
 </script>
```

The ids array will have ur new array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using jquery's grep:

```
var test1=[{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 1},{apx: "45.406/19.292", id: 2},{apx: "45.406/19.300",        id: 3}]
var found;
found= $.grep(test1,function(o,i)
          {
              for(var ii=0;ii< test1.length;ii++)
              {
                  return o.apx == test1[ii].apx;
              }

          })
console.log(found);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfWAm/27/)